# Installing Haskell Gloss

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm having the most difficult time trying to understand what I am doing wrong with installing haskell on windows. I've downloaded the platform binary and ran the .exe file. Afterwards the instructions on their hackage website tells me to run cabal install gloss.

Whenever I try this in their GHCI shell, I get the following errors:

```
<interactive>:1:1: Not in scope 'cabal'
<interactive>:1:7: Not in scope 'install'
<interactive>:1:15: Not in scope 'gloss'
```

I know for a fact `cabal install gloss` isn't the correct command, but I can't seem to find anything online that'll help me figure this out. Would much appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to run this in Command Prompt (or something), not in GHCi. (I don't know the actual process on Windows, so I can't/won't answer.)

Comment: the haskell platform bundle doesn't come with the GHC...they never make it easy =S

Comment: "the haskell platform bundle doesn't come with the GHC"?! Uh... yes it does!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Click Start → Run. Type `cmd` and press Enter. A Windows command prompt window will appear, in which you can run the `cabal install gloss` command.