# Could not find module ‘Text.Regex.Posix’

Tags: haskell

I want to try doing regexes in GHCi. I tried loading the module

```
 :mod +Text.Regex.Posix
```

But got this error instead

```
<no location info>:
    Could not find module ‘Text.Regex.Posix’
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
```

But I should have Text installed

`ghc-pkg find-module Text.Regex.Posix` would give me

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.8.4/lib/ghc-7.8.4/package.conf.d
/Users/a/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-7.8.4/package.conf.d
```

What do I do?

I have no problem with this though:

```
import Text.Read
```

Why?

Comment: Try running `cabal install regex-posix`.  The output from `ghc-pkg` you're seeing is just the listings of what package databases GHC is currently seeing, unless you see an actual package name listed under one of those then you don't have that module available.

Comment: @bheklilr cool story bro. #ProblemSolved. +1.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that you simply don't have the `regex-posix` package installed.  This is the package that exports the `Text.Regex.Posix` module.  `Text.Read` is exported by the `base` package which comes with every Haskell distribution.

You can see this by running `ghc-pkg find-module Text.Read`.  To install the `regex-posix` package globally run the command `cabal install regex-posix`.  If you don't want to install it globally or run into problems getting it to install, it would be better to try installing it with the same command in a sandbox after running `cabal sandbox init` in the directory of your choice.

Comment: If you're on Stack, you can do `stack ghci --package regex-posix` followed by `:m +Text.Regex.Posix`.

Comment: I successfully installed `regex-posix-0.95-2`, it’s in `~/.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org`, restarted, `ghci`, and I still get the error above.

Comment: Also, if anyone wonders why these commands do not work for them, see [a related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665843/installing-haskell-gloss).

Comment: I had to do a `cabal install --lib regex-posix` for the library to be available within GHCi.